# read more and read less jquery issue

Tags: jquery, html

```
<p class="pra">
```

SimpleText is the native text editor for the Apple Macintosh OS in versions before OS X. SimpleText allows editing including text formatting (underline, italic, bold SimpleText is the native text editor for the Apple Macintosh OS in versions before OS X. SimpleText allows editing including text formatting (underline, italic, bold SimpleText is the native text editor for the Apple Macintosh OS in versions before OS X. SimpleText allows editing including text formatting (underline, italic, bold SimpleText is the native text editor for the Apple Macintosh OS in versions before OS X. SimpleText allows editing including text formatting (underline, italic, bold

```
<script>
$(document).ready(function() {
if($('.pra').text().length >= 100) {
var txt= $('.pra').text();
var res =txt.slice(1,105);
//alert( res);
$('.pra').html(res+'.....'+'...<a class="readmore" href="#">&emsp;Read More</a>');
}
$('.readmore').on('click',function(){
$(this).parent('p.pra').html(txt+'.....'+'...<a class="readless" href="#">&emsp;Read Less</a>');
$('.readless').on('click',function(){
if($('.pra').text().length >= 100) {
var txt= $('.pra').text();
var res =txt.slice(1,105);
//alert( res);
$('.pra').html(res+'.....'+'...<a class="readmore" href="#">&emsp;Read More</a>');  
}
});
});
});
</script>
```

when i click Read more oppening full content if press Read Less it is    showing less content up to this no problem but again second time i click Read More no action and no more content not displying
[Demo Link](https://jsfiddle.net/YogeshDV/mp4x9tLy/5/)

Answer (score 2):

Instead of:

```
$('.readmore').on('click',function(){...});
```

try with:

```
$('body').on('click','.readmore',function(){...});
```

Same with `'.readless'`

Also change `txt.slice(1,105);` with `txt.slice(0,105);`

Or your text will lose the first letter everytime

```js
 
$(document).ready(function() {
 
 //alert('fddf');
 if($('.pra').text().length >= 100) {

  var txt= $('.pra').text();
   var res =txt.slice(0,105);
   //alert( res);
   $('.pra').html(res+'.....'+'...<a class="readmore" href="#">&emsp;Read More</a>');
   
}

        $('body').on('click','.readmore',function(){
              $(this).parent('p.pra').html(txt+'.....'+'...<a class="readless" href="#">&emsp;Read Less</a>');


        $('body').on('click','.readless',function(){
         if($('.pra').text().length >= 100) {

  var txt= $('.pra').text();
   var res =txt.slice(0,105);
   //alert( res);
   $('.pra').html(res+'.....'+'...<a class="readmore" href="#">&emsp;Read More</a>');
   
}

        });

 });
 });
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<p class="pra">
SimpleText is the native text editor for the Apple Macintosh OS in versions before OS X. SimpleText allows editing including text formatting (underline, italic, bold SimpleText is the native text editor for the Apple Macintosh OS in versions before OS X. SimpleText allows editing including text formatting (underline, italic, bold SimpleText is the native text editor for the Apple Macintosh OS in versions before OS X. SimpleText allows editing including text formatting (underline, italic, bold SimpleText is the native text editor for the Apple Macintosh OS in versions before OS X. SimpleText allows editing including text formatting (underline, italic, bold
</p>
```